# Filter values from list of dicts by list of values

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
data = [{'key1':'a', 'key2':'100', 'varying key/value pairs'}, {'key1':'b', 'key2':'50', 'varying key/value pairs'}, {'key1':'a', 'key2':'100', 'varying key/value pairs'}, {'key1':'b', 'key2':'50', 'varying key/value pairs'}, {'key1':'c', 'key2':'150', 'varying key/value pairs'},...]
```

And I have a list of filters like this (which can vary by case in content and length):

```
filter = ['a', 'b']
```

And I want to make create new new dictionary, but eliminate double counting like this:

```
new_data = [{'key1':'a', 'key2':'100'}, {'key1':'b', 'key2':'50'}]
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: The filter list is only for `key1`?

Comment: Have you tried converting your `list` to a `set` and then again to a `list`? This is common practice to remove duplicate elements in a list.

Comment: What happened to `'varying key/value pairs'` in the output? Why are these not included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to select the valid keys and a temporary dictionary (as a dictionary comprehension) to remove the duplicates?

```
S = {'a', 'b'}

new_data = list({d['key1']: d for d in data if d['key1'] in S}.values())
```

Output:

```
[{'key1': 'a', 'key2': '100'}, {'key1': 'b', 'key2': '50'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can first convert the list to a set and then convert it back to list. Note that the order of the dict in new list may not be the same as the order as before, as sets are unordered by nature.

```
unique_keys = {d['key1']: d['key2'] for d in data if d['key1'] in filters}
new_data = [{'key1': k, 'key2': v} for k, v in unique_keys.items()]
```